# how to separate array with commas?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

i have this $_categories as array()

`<?php print_r($_categories); ?>` is this:  Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 7 )

what i need is to extract de values 13 and 7 into this format: 13,7 (without comma after the last value).

i have this code but is not there yet... the result is: 137 and not 13,7

```
<?php
    if ( is_array($_categories) ) {
        foreach ($_categories as $key => $value) {
            $out = array();
            array_push($out, $value);
            echo implode(', ', $out);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo '<li>There are no saved values yet.</li>';
    }
?>
```

Thanks, nelson

Comment: I believe you ask here because you haven't read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: Hi Alvin. Actually i have read the manual, but my php knowledge is very poor and didn't applied the direct/simple solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly use

```
echo implode(', ', $_categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you are `implode`ing just one element,and `echo`ing just it. Try like this:

```
$out = array();   //putting outside of the loop
foreach ($_categories as $key => $value) {
    array_push($out, $value);
}    
echo implode(', ', $out);   //putting outside of the loop
```