# How to get the keys from values = 1 from a multicheckbox array?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671733/how-to-separate-array-with-commas) I learned how to make an implode.

But now I need something a little more complicated (I think) and after searching I tried several implode options without clear results, here I am again to ask help...

I have a multicheckboxes which are populated with categories (**Wordpress**).

Each category name has a category id and the value for the checkbox is 1 for checked.

So, this is an echo of an example array after check some categories:

```
<?php $categories = of_get_option('check_categories' ); ?>

<?php print_r($categories); ?>

Array ( 
    [13] => 1 
    [7] => 1 
    [6] => 1 
    [23] => 0 
    [12] => 0 
    [5] => 0 
    [11] => 0 
    [22] => 0     
    [3] => 0 
    [14] => 0 
    [1] => 1 
    [17] => 0 
    [10] => 0 
    [18] => 1 
)
```

If i make `<?php echo implode(', ',of_get_option('check_categories' )); ?>`

This is the result: `1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1`

OK... But I don't want these results, what I need is: for checkboxes = 1 I need to get only the category Id (keys). In this case exactly like this: `13,7,6,1,18` but how?

Answer (score 2):

I just solved it.It's quiet simple in fact.

I used function implode with the search within the array_keys to select only the keys with value 1:

```
<?php echo implode(', ',array_keys($categoriesblog2, 1)); ?>
```

And the final result is (witch are the categories id from my blog):

```
13, 7, 6, 1, 18
```